# Mailchimp For dev

Tags: wordpress

I want to cusomer a send mail automation in the Mailchimp. I use plugin Mailchimp for woocommerce. I click button checkout and it get data true but it is not send. I use option Recover abandoned carts and about 1 hour it send.

Do you know plugin or custom short time in the code when send?